no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::function<int>(int)>’
I`m try to write a class for parse *.so, when compile, got error: no matching function for call to...

error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<std::result_of<std::function<int>(it)>'


, the code as follow:
    template<typename T>
    std::function<T> get_function(const string& funcName) {
        auto it = m_map.find(funcName);
        if (it == m_map.end()) {
            auto addr = dlsym(m_libHandler, funcName.c_str());
            if (nullptr == addr) {
                return nullptr;
            }

            m_map.emplace(std::make_pair(funcName, addr));
            it = m_map.find(funcName);
        }

        return std::function<T>((T*)(it->second));
    }

592  template<typename T, typename... Args>
593    typename std::result_of<std::function<T>(Args...)>::type excecute_func(const string& funcName,             Args&&... args) {
594        auto f = get_function<T>(funcName);
595        if (nullptr == f) {
596            string s = "can not find this function" + funcName;
597            throw std::exception(s.c_str());
598        }
599
600        return std::ref(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

int main() {
        int ret = doip_lib_client.excecute_func<int, int>("init_doip_client", 1);

}

error as follow:
cplusplus_prac.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
cplusplus_prac.cpp:615:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘SoParser::excecute_func<int, int>(const char [17], int)’
  615 |         ret = doip_lib_client.excecute_func<int, int>("init_doip_client", 1);
      |                                                                            ^
cplusplus_prac.cpp:593:62: note: candidate: ‘template<class T, class ... Args> typename std::result_of<std::function<T>(Args ...)>::type SoParser::excecute_func(const string&, Args&& ...)’
  593 |     typename std::result_of<std::function<T>(Args...)>::type excecute_func(const string& funcName, Args&&... args) {
      |                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
cplusplus_prac.cpp:593:62: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
cplusplus_prac.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class T, class ... Args> typename std::result_of<std::function<T>(Args ...)>::type SoParser::excecute_func(const string&, Args&& ...) [with T = int; Args = {int}]’:
cplusplus_prac.cpp:615:76:   required from here
cplusplus_prac.cpp:593:62: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::function<int>(int)>’

any one could help, where is the problem
search on the internet, try to fix it, but not work

I`ve resolve ti : int ret = doip_lib_client.excecute_func<int(int)>("init_doip_client", 1);

It seems the first template parameter of excecute_func is meant to be a function type, e.g. void(int). You are passing plain int. std::function<int> doesn't make sense. Perhaps you meant the first parameter to be a return type, and Args to be parameter types - then say so, as in std::function<T(Args...)>. Though in this case result_of wouldn't seem to be necessary - the result of a function returning T is, well, T.

You should rename the type T to Signature everywhere in the provided code.
Then this line:
int ret = doip_lib_client.excecute_func<int, int>("init_doip_client", 1);

should re rewritten to be:
int ret = doip_lib_client.excecute_func<int(int)>("init_doip_client", 1);

and things should generally work.
The trick is that the (poorly named) T template argument is the signature of the function you are wrapping.  Which in this case, is a function that takes an int and returns an int, aka int(int).

std::function<T>, with T = int is not a valid specialisation of std::function, and even if it were, std::function<T>(Args...) is a function type that takes Args... and returns a std::function<T>.
It looks like T is your result type, so you don't need typename std::result_of<???>::type at all.
Also note that std::ref here is also invalid, the overload taking an rvalue is = deleted. If you need a function that returns a reference, pass a reference type as T.
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T excecute_func(const string& funcName, Args&&... args) {
    auto f = get_function<T(Args...)>(funcName);
    if (nullptr == f) {
        throw std::runtime_error("can not find this function" + funcName);
    }
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

